# How to compare if the values of a data frame A contain one of the values of data frame B?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, compare

In R, say you have a matrix A:

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), nrow=6, ncol=3)
```

and another matrix B:

```
B <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17), nrow=6, ncol=2)
```

and you want to see, if in each line the values in A are one of the values of the corresponding line in B by checking each value seperatly.

E.g. You would like to see if the values in the first row of A (1, 7, 13) are equal to either 1 or 7 (first row of B).

How could you do that?

My problem is, that the two matrizes are not of equal size and I would like to get a matrix in the size of A which contains either a TRUE or a FALSE.

E.g.: The first line of this result matrix C would be (TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), since 1 is equal to 1 or 7, 7 is equal to 1 or 7, but 13 is not equal to 1 or 7.

I have tried solutions with %in%, but since I am pretty new to R I couldn´t find out, how to apply it to every row and not just the first one. A solution with "==" didn´t work either, because the matrizes didn´t have the same size and I want to compare every cell of A with both numbers of B and not cell by cell.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply()` over the row indices of `A` like so:

```
sapply(seq(length = nrow(A)), function(x) A[x, ] %in% B[x, ])
#>       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]
#> [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
#> [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This results in a matrix where each column corresponds to a row in `A`. To transpose it you can use `t()`

```
t(sapply(seq(length = nrow(A)), function(x) A[x, ] %in% B[x, ]) )
#>      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#> [1,] TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#> [2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [4,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [5,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
#> [6,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Very nice, thank´s a lot! This is exactly what I wanted, altough I have not quiet understood how sapply() works. seq stands for how often the function should be applied, right? And length = nrow(A) count the number of rows which is used as number of how often the function is repeated, right? What does x stand for then?

Comment: `seq()` creates a sequence of numbers, one for each row of the matrix `A`. `sapply()` then applies a function for each number. In this case we define our own function `function(x) A[x, ] %in% B[x, ]` where `x` is the row number, and it's used to subset `A` and `B`. `sapply()` passes each value from `seq()` into the function as `x`.

Comment: Thank you so very much, you made my day!